# Problems with deploying an exploded WAR to a Tomcat 6 server in IntelliJ Idea 12.1.4 Ultimate

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat6, war

I'm trying to debug a web app in IntelliJ Idea, which is deployed to a local Tomcat 6 server in form of an exploded WAR.

At the start of the application I get `ClassNotFoundExceptions`, even though the exploded WAR directory contains those classes (in its `WEB-INF/classe` subdirectory).

When I launch the web app in IntelliJ Idea (press the `Debug 'Tomcat'` button) and look into the Tomcat *webapp* directory (`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps`), I don't see there a directory with my exploded WAR.

Therefore, I think that the exploded WAR is not copied to the respective Tomcat directory.

How can I fix this (make sure that Tomcat sees all class files from my exploded WAR directory) ?

**Update 1 (18.09.2013 13:46 MSK):**

Here's the stack trace:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
SEVERE: Exception invoking method manageApp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ru/mycompany/MyClass
    at ru.mycompany.MyCustomRealm.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.mycompany.MyClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 42 more

сен 18, 2013 1:38:26 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
SEVERE: Exception invoking method createStandardContext
javax.management.RuntimeErrorException: Error invoking method manageApp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:308)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ru/mycompany/MyClass
    at ru.mycompany.MyCustomRealm.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.mycompany.MyClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Could you check server output in IDEA? It should print the current CATALINA_BASE. I remember IDEA doesn't use tomcat's default webapps directory.

Comment: It actually prints something like `java -Dcatalina.base=somedir`. `somedir` does not contain the files of my exploded WAR.

Comment: Check your tomcat configuration. In Deployment tab, add the corresponding deploy in "Deploy at the server startup".

Comment: The exploded WAR artifact was always present in *Deploy at the server startup* list.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar app which happens to be a maven project, and by default it uses the target (output) directory. However this can be verified by:

1. Look for the following line in the startup log `Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\xxxxx\.IntelliJIdea12\system\tomcat\Unnamed_bpt_5"`
2. Go into the directory specified in the log message, then into `conf\Catalina\localhost`
3. Open the xml from the folder and check the `docBase`

Also, please ensure that on the `Run/Debug configuration` page in the `Before launch` section you have added `Make` (or maven package) goal so it will compile your classes and resources

Comment: `docBase` points to the directory with the exploded WAR (and it contains all required files in the `WEB-INF/classes` subdirectory).

Comment: In the *Before launch* section I have 2 items - *Make* and *Build ... exploded artifact*.

Comment: My Tomcat home directory contains spaces (`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0`). Can this be a problem?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko I am not quite sure about your problem. Where do you get ClassNotFoundException? In Tomcat console or IDEA?

Comment: In the Tomcat console inside Idea (*Debugger -> Server*). The error occurs in the `start` method of a custom realm (sub-class of `RealmBase`).

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko what's your tomcat configuration? Is it local? Could you post your stack trace?

Comment: @lhuang It's local. You can find the stack trace in Update 1.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko what's your project's web deployment setting? Check Project Structure -> Modules -> Web -> Source roots. Does it include all required source directories?

Comment: Yes! It produces an exploded WAR directory with `WEB-INF/classes/ru/mycompany/MyClass.class` file. The `docBase` attribute points to the exploded WAR directory.

Comment: MyCustomRealm may suggest that you have created your own Realm implementation. If that is the case, the classes corresponding to the logic behind the realm should be in the tomcat lib directory, and not in your web apps's classes folder: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#What_is_a_Realm?